# Does SDAC display data for both the PFD, ND and the ECAM display?

Tags: avionics, airbus-a320

On the Airbus A320 the System Data Acquisition Concentrators (SDAC) aquire system data, process it and sends system page data to the three Display Management Computers (DMC). The DMC process the data and generate an image.

- Is this for the PFD and ND only? Or does the DMC also generate the image for the upper and lower ECAM too?

[image]
<sup>EIS, [source](https://fr.scribd.com/doc/64243457/Airbus-A320-ATA-31-EIS-Presentation)</sup>

If the lower ECAM, supplied by DMC 2, fails then the E/WD displays which has priority take its place; and DMC 1 normally supplies the Engine/Warning Display (E/WD).

- Does it mean DMC 1 has a channel or a way to display on the lower ECAM as it just did?
- Likewise, does DMC 2, which normally supplies the lower ECAM, have a channel or some sort of way to display on the upper ECAM?

Answer (score 1):

The DMC can process simultaneously 3 pages among them only one system page. DMC 1 and DMC2 are linked to both central displays.

Therefore the display page arrangement is done by the DMCs not by the SDACs, nevertheless lot of data computed by the SDACs are displayed on the ECAMS and on the PFD and on the ND:

- On the ECAMs for instance all system pages and AMBER alarms via the FWCs
- On the ND and on the PFD flags and degraded conditions, such as the cross « X » when data is NOT computed for the relevant parameter.

Of course my answer is not exhaustif but sufficient to justify that the SDACs are concerned by data displayed on all EIS displays.